# Brackets in URL Field Get Reformatted to %5B%5D

Tags: entities

I have a Drupal 7 site with a content type that includes a link field.  The intention is for staff to add a link that can link to an outside website. But if that link contains brackets [ ], the module uses %5B %5D instead. It also, cuts out parts of the URL.

So, ....

...Search/Results?lookfor=&basicType=Keyword&type=Keyword&filter[]=local_time_since_added

would translate to

...Search/Results?type=Keyword&filter%5B%5D=local_time_since_added

Would anyone be able to advise me as to why the link field in a content type would not only remove parts of my URL but also replace brackets?

I see a lot of chatter about this with views, but not on a link field in a content type.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not come up with an answer to my question, the easy work-around I created was to add a text field instead of a URL field in my content type.

I then used the [Linked Field Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) to link the text field to the outside website.  This preserved all of the crazy characters that were needed.

For those not familiar with the [Linked Field Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field), after you have added a text field to your content type, go into:

1. Manage Display for your content type
2. Set the Format to Default
3. Click on the Gear Symbol
4. Say No to link to content
5. Check the box to Link the field
6. For Destination use the field item name with dashes, like this [node:field-online-link-to-resource]
7. Use the Advanced section to add a title, link text, etc.

FYI that I would only allow trusted content editors to add data to this type of field.